# Mac OS X terminal killall won't kill running process

Tags: macos, terminal

I have an instance of lighttpd running. When I do "ps -axc" the process is listed as

```
"614 ?? 0:00.15 lighttpd"
```

But when I do "killall lighttpd" I get

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.5.6. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per the other response, if it's not your process, prepend `sudo` if you're an administrator. If not, you may be out of luck.

Also, try `sudo killall -9 lighttpd` which sends the specific signal KILL instead of TERM.

Just to be sure you can also try `sudo kill -9 614` using the PID.

Comment: Ok this did it. What happend was that I had created a lighttpd.plist and added it to /library/launchdaemons, then loaded it with launchctl. It was running under root instead of my user account. It was killing the proc, but immediately was being reloaded.

Answer (score 5):

Is the task written in the ps aux list in brackets? If so, it is a zombie, it is waiting some I/O task, which probably never completes. You can't kill it as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Does it belong to you ? If you do

```
ps aux | grep lighttpd
```

that will give you the user id associated with that process (I'm guessing it's `chowned` to another user)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo kill -9 `pgrep lighttpd`
```

Answer (score 0):

It works: `killall -u root -c lighttpd`